# Uniform convergence in the Laurent coefficients proof, why?

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Using the Laurent-expansion of $f(z)$ around $0$

$$f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n z^n + \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} b_n z^{-n} \tag{1}$$

> *Theorem*
>
> The coefficients of the Laurent series are given by the formulae:
>
> $$a_m = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma \frac{f(z)}{z^{m+1}} \text{d}z \qquad b_m = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\Gamma z^{m-1} f(z) \text{d}z$$
>
> where $\Gamma$ is any circle $|z-z_0| = \rho,\; 0< r < \rho < R$.

I understand why $f(z)$ is uniformly convergent *(because both series are uniformly convergent)* over $\Gamma$. But I'm experiencing some problems in the proof of these coefficients.

> *Proof*
>
> Since the series (1) is uniformly  convergent on $\Gamma$ the **same will be true** of the series obtained by muliplying (1) with:
>
> $$\text{either}\qquad  z^{m-1}\qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac{1}{z^{m+1}}$$
>
> Then the proof continues by swapping sum and integral (for which the uniform convergence is required) ...

#### Why?

Could someone provide an argument why that **same will be true** is valid?

Comment: Because the tail sum only changes by a factor of $R^{m-1}$ or $1/r^{m+1}$?

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of $z^{m-1}$ and $1/z^{m+1}$ will be constants on a circle centered around 0.

Suppose $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly on $\Gamma$ to $f(z)$ and that $g(z)$ is some function such that $|g(z)| = \rho$ on $\Gamma$.

$|g(z)f_n(z) - g(z)f(z)| = |g(z)||f_n(z) - f(z)| = \rho |f_n(z) - f(z)|$

So if the RHS is bounded by $\epsilon$ then the LHS is bounded by $\epsilon / \rho$ which shows $g f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $g f$.

Your situation is that $g(z) = z^{\pm m \pm 1}$ which is indeed a constant on $\Gamma$ which is a circle around $0$.